# 422 Unprocessable Entity in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, phoenix-framework

I am trying to put data from Angular 8 on localhost:4200 to an API on localhost:4000. In Postman the validation error message is working , but Angular getting Unprocessable Entity. In angular how to get error message "{"errors":{"phone":["has already been taken"]}}" shown in postman

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Angular service api:

```
        updateCustomer(id: string, any: any): Observable<any> {
        const url = http://127.0.0.1:4000/admin/users/${id}`;
        return this.http.put(url, any).pipe(
            map(
                res => {
                    return res;
                }
            )
        );
    }

    update(): void {
    let data = { user: this.customerForm.value }
    this.apiService.updateCustomer(this.id, data)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => console.log(data),
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G4Jw.png)

console-log:(getting only 'OK')

zone-evergreen.js:2952 PUT http://127.0.0.1:4000/admin/users/3 422
customer-form.component.ts:106 OK

Comment: Postman did also receive a 422 Unprocessable entity (in the upper right area of your picture). This is not the error message but the Http status that your backend is returning.

Comment: yes, in angular how to get error message "{"errors":{"phone":["has already been taken"]}}" shown in postman.

Comment: It should be encapsulated in the `error` object in your error callback. Can you show us what get's logged to the console?

Comment: getting only 'OK '